# Merge multiple search form results in one with Ransack , Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, sorting, ransack

I have **Rails 4** app with **Ransack** for search and sorting.

This far I managed to search and sort using **Ajax**. Works great.

First of all user selects region by clicking on checkbox. Ajax returns all records that are associated with selected region. Then user can sort just one of 5 available columns example height, weight and age..

My code so far.

**Controller:**

```
 @search = @adver.search(params[:q])    
 @search.sorts = ['height asc','age asc','votes_for.size asc'] if @search.sorts.empty?
 @advertisements = @search.result(distinct: true)
```

View:
   **1- Selects region**

```
<%= search_form_for @search, :id=>"search_regions",:remote=>"true", url: advertisements_path, :method => :get do |f| %>                                                     
          <% @regions.each_slice(20) do |slice| -%>
                     <div class="pull-left">                                                                                    
                       <ul>                     
                         <% slice.each do |region| -%>
                            <li>  

                            <%= check_box_tag 'q[region_id_eq_any][]', region.id, false, :required => false, :id => region.id ,:html =>{:class=>"region-checkboxes"}, :onchange=>"$('#search_regions').submit();"%>
                                                    <label style="left: 0px;" for=<%=region.id%>><span><%=region.name%> </span>                                                                             
                            </li>
                         <% end -%>     

                      </ul>
                    </div>
        <% end -%> 
<%end%>




    ****2 - Sorts by columns****


        <%= search_form_for @search, :class=>"search",:remote=>"true", url: advertisements_path, :method => :get do |f| %>

              <%= f.text_field :name_or_phone_number_or_identifier_cont, :id=>"search-field-keyup",:class=>"form-control",:placeholder => "Meklēt pēc ID,vārda vai telefona numura" %>      
              <%= sort_link(@search, :height,"AUGUMS",{},{ :remote => true, :method => :get }) %>
              <%= sort_link(@search, :age,"VECUMS", {hide_indicator: false},{ :remote => true, :method => :get }) %>          
              <%= sort_link(@search, 'votes_for.size',"REITINGS", {hide_indicator: false},{ :remote => true, :method => :get }) %>  
        <%end%>
```

**Problem:**

When I select region Ajax returns all associated records as expected. When I want to sort for example by height previous search clears and ajax sorts all records not just those that was in chosen region.

This is because I have separate search forms, but with the same name @  ?
Any other way to achieve this. ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is because I have separate search forms

Yeah, you are absolutely right: the issue is that you have two different forms. By the time user makes decisions in the latter form, data from the first one is left above. Browser does not send information about `region` along with `height` or `age` and this ends up in a wrong sorting/filtering.

What I would do here is attaching some `javascript` function to handle the second form's submission. This function would obtain data from the second form, add value of selected `region` from the first one manually, and send this to server.

Comment: Thanks, do you have some idea how that javascript function should look like in example ?

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds you could check examples at jquery ajax page to get an idea of how to send data asynchroniously: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Hi, i just now wrapped up both checkboxes and sort links inside single search form, but still I got this issue. Can't merge multiple search queries.

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds not sure if I can say anything particular without looking at your code. may be you should update your question or post a new one with your current code snippets.

Comment: I created new question to keep it separate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30822330/merge-search-and-sort-queries-with-rails-ransack

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds the problem stays the same: you're trying to achieve it with `remote` form instead of `javascript`. Not sure if it's possible this way. But may be somebody would give you an advice from another point of view.

Comment: Thanks, but can you provide some example of the code that can do such thing. I am not expert in Javascript yet, so I have dificulties to understand your idea.